# Unable To Serve Webp Images Through htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, webp

*Before I start explaining my problem I want to point out that I'm a BCA student and currently in the learning phase. I'm not an experienced developer. I work part-time in an IT firm as an senior in-house SEO executive (Senior because I have been working here for more than 2 years.) I'm currently learning python and have good knowledge in HTML and CSS.*

***The problem***
Recently I decided to update all the large size png/jpg images of my website with next-gen (As referred by Google Page Speed) webp format. I followed this guide from web.dev (https://web.dev/articles/serve-images-webp) and one from Digital ocean ([www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website](http://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website)), As my company's website is quite humongous with around 70-80K pages and 100K+ images, I decided to go with mod_rewrite method. Though I can utilize PHP or even Python to edit the htmls, but due to the sheer number of pages, I opted mod_rewrite method. I added this code to my .htaccess file, which is at the root of my website.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/webp/$1.webp -f
  RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.jpe?g|\.png)$ %1\.webp [L,T=image/webp,R] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

Here I made a slight change and added a separate directory to store the webp (ROOT/assets/webp/). Unfortunately this rewrite is not working.

I surfed the internet for possible solutions but all my attempts were futile. I tried plenty of things to troubleshoot the problem but was unable to do so.

1. I changed the counterpart webp filename to img.png.webp
2. I Presumed as there are plenty of redirects setup by me the mod_rewrite is on in apache configuration.
3. As we are self hosted, I asked the IT guy to reload the Apache server.

Nothing is working. In my desperate attempt I even asked GPT AI Model to rectify the problem but was suggested with same troubleshooting methods that I performed above.

**More Info**

1. Structure of my assets/webp folder is domain.com/assets/webp/
   The pngs are in dir domain.com/assets/img/
2. No rewrite errors in Apache logs
3. mod_rewrite and mod_headers are enabled.
4. .htaccess location is root i.e mydomain.com/.htaccess (Maybe I'm putting it at wrong place IDK.)

After some R&D and suggestions from comments I updated the code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteCond /assets/webp/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule ^ /assets/webp/%1.webp [L,T=image/webp,E=accept:1]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$">
        Header append Vary Accept
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But this is also not working. I'm at my wits end. Tried so many things since yesterday nothing is working.

Finally @arkascha 's fix have given me the resolution final rules in my htaccess -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/assets/img/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/webp/%1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^ /assets/webp/%1.webp [L,T=image/webp,E=accept:1]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$">
        Header append Vary Accept
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: To me it looks like the folders in condition and rule are simply not correct. Please add a sketch for the folder layout to the question. And examples of incoming requests to those images.

Comment: Also I am confused by the `R` flag you specify in your rewriting rule. That means an external redirection is triggered. _Why_? That means _two_ requests for each image. Why not simply use an _internal_ rewrite?

Comment: "Please add a sketch for the folder layout to the question. And examples of incoming requests to those images." Can you dumb this down a little. I apologize but I'm still still at learning curve for these kinf of things.

Comment: "Dumb this down"? The folder layout: your folders, their structure. Incoming request: the requested URL that you are trying to rewrite.

Comment: Oh, Okay, The requested URL is mydomian/assests/img/img.png. The URL that I want to serve is mydomain/assets/webp/img.webp. Basically all my images (png, jpg, gif) are in mydomain/assests/img/ and I have their webp counterparts in mydomain/assets/webp/.

Comment: UPDATE: I have checked whether the mod_rewrite and mod_header are enabled or not from serevers WHM, They are indeed enabled.

Comment: What is so difficult with "add to the question"? There is an "edit" button below your question. Add additional information to the question, not here in comments where it is hard to read.

Comment: I think in `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/webp/$1.webp -f` the `$1` contains the whole requested path including the file name, not just the file name. Which would mean that the condition never is fullfilled.

Comment: I have added the more info in the question. What do you suggest I do then? replace $1 with what?

Comment: Probably something into that direction: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/assets/img/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$ 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/webp/%1.webp -f`

Comment: HOLY CRAP! THIS WORKS!

Comment: @arkascha If i want to add more directory can I use the same rewrite condition? My webp images will be in same directory. e.g RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
 ^/assets/portfolio/images/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$ or RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
 ^/blogimages/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$

Comment: No, since then it is unclear what `%1` refers to. Instead you'd need to combine both conditions: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/blogimages|/assets/portfolio)/images/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$`. Or, mybe easier to read, thus to maintain over time, would be two separated blocks if conditions and rules, once per such folder.

Comment: A general hint: why don't you simply test such a suggestion yourself? That way you will learn a lot. And you have the proof that things work as expected, once you get them to work. So go, setup a simply test in your local development environment. You can do that independent from the application. Just make a folder with those asset folders inside. And add your configuration file with the rules you want to get working. Test it.

Comment: Noted, I will test some combinations, for starter I used [OR] after every unique RedirectCondition but after seeing your latest comment I'm going to try some more combinations. Anyways, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use that code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.webp -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.webp [L,T=image/webp]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$">
        Header append Vary Accept
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

as arkascha mentioned, the "R" looks wrong.

Comment: okay, I got that that extra R is not good. So I tried your code (modified it a little bit to satisfy my need to request webp images from another directory. It still doesn't work. I changed only this line - RewriteRule ^ /assets/webp/%1.webp [L,T=image/webp]

Comment: Try to use /assets/webp/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}1.webp [L,T=image/webp]